# docker run -gpus all with multiple volume for yolov5

Tags: docker, docker-volume, yolov5, gpu-shared-memory

```
docker run --gpus all --shm-size=4gb  --name bookfinalfinal  --volume D:/BankDataDocker/data:/usr/src/app/data   --volume D:/BankDataDocker/run:/usr/src/app/runs  yolo:v1 bash
```

docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /usr/src/app/data.

I have tried changing into

```
docker run --gpus all --shm-size=4gb  --name bookfinalfinal  --volume /D/BankDataDocker/data:/usr/src/app/data   --volume /D/BankDataDocker/run:/usr/src/app/runs  yolo:v1 bash
```

successfully created a container however docker do not connect the volume directory, i can not access the local system file

or adding  / in front of local system and docker container however both fails

I tried multiple solution from stackoverflow but still fails

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like this is in Windows ? Docker is mostly used on linux systems , so please specify the operating system.

Comment: sorry for not specifying and yes i use docker on window